# Simple CanCan problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have just started with CanCan and here's a sample of the code:

```
# Ability.rb
def initialize(user)    
  user ||= User.new      

  can :read, Link
end

# view.html.erb
<% if can? :read, @link %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This is from the github repo for CanCan but this doesn't seem to work (it returns false and stops the `...` code from running).

When I change the view to `<% if can? :read, Link %>`, it works. But, this is different to the CanCan readme. Do you know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: What is this: `user || User.new `?

Comment: "CanCan expects a current_user method to exist". Do you have `current_user` method available?

Comment: I do have a current_user. The `user || User.new` just initializes a new user so we don't get any failures in the process. It's in Ryan Bates' original Railscast on CanCan.

Comment: This failure is occurring for a logged in user - I'm trying to display/hide a button depending on whether they have the ability to read @link or not.

Comment: In the Railscast it seems to be `user ||= User.new`

Comment: Apologies - that's what I meant. It's a typo here... fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
can? :read, Link
```

is the concept of a link... something to the akin of "Can you read all links?"

```
can :read, Link do |link|
  link.account.id == user.account_id
end
```

This checks to make sure you can read the specific link object in question

Answer (score 1):

Check that

1. You don't have anything granting or removing rights to Link models below the line you displayed
2. @link is not nil and is a Link

Comment: @David, if @link is nil and/or not a Link on the page with the `link_to`, do I have to initialize a `@link` or should I just use `Link` (in the view's if statement)?

Comment: @sscirrus: I think you shouldn't try to output link at all if `@link` doesn't exist.

Comment: @David. What I mean is: let's say I'm on a Project page and I want to see if the `current_user` can create a Link (if they can I'll display a button called 'New link'). In this case, I still need to use something, right?

Comment: Sorry @Heikki I wasn't paying attention - I meant you in my last comment! :)

Comment: If there is no link, what I would do is check permissions on Link.new (which is adapted to most cases): can? :read, Link.new

Comment: Maybe those conditionals should be `<% if can? :read, @link %>` for displaying existing link and `<% if can? :create, Link %>` for link creation? At least for me it would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah... this is the distinction I'm trying to get at now. Assuming no @link exists at the source page, should we use `Link` or `Link.new`?

Comment: I usually prefer to test authorization on Link.new. That way, if I have conditions based (e.g.) on relationships or other methods, no Exception will be raised. In other words, if a link `:has_many followers` and users can edit links with less than 10 followers (i.e. @link.followers.count < 10), passing Link.new will work correctly (since Link.new.followers.count == 0). However, Link.followers will raise an error (since no such static method exists). Basically, the advantage of using Link.new over Link is that the first will work where the 2nd does, but the converse is not true.